# Save the Datetime in UTC in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am facing problem with saving date time in UTC.
I amtaking datetime as input from user after that I want to save that datetime's UTC value in database.
I am using one text box(for taking the exact date) and one dropdownlist(for taking the hours of that date)to get the datetime input values from user.
below is my code to get the exact input datetime from user after combinending both controls value.
like:25/12/2011 as date and 10 hours as hours after combinding both values the date values is 25/12/2011 10:00 AM
fort his calculation I am using below code:

```
      string[] dateArray = HdnDPC_date1.Value.Split('/');
            string dtt = dateArray[1] + "/" + dateArray[0] + "/" + dateArray[2];
            var fdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtt);

           DateTime dadate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dateArray[2]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArray[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateArray[0]));
            dadate = Convert.ToDateTime(fdate).AddHours(deadlineHr);
```

**below code is used to convert the date time value in UTC**

```
            DateTime DeadLine = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dadate);
```

but code is not converting the input datetime according to the Time zone, it is always convert according to the **"Central Time Zone, USA & Canada"**
But I want to convert that datetime according to the user's Timezone.

Please help me to identify this problem why this happened.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the `ToUniversalTime` function

```
DateTime univDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

More on `ToUniveralTime` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: You'll have to tell it what to convert **from**

Comment: @Shai: ToUniveralTime  time always give the Time according to Local timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the user's timezone. For example:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dadate, 
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your thread's current culture to the user's culture like:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage); 
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx